# Remove date from Wordpress medias & images url permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to remove the date from my permalink images.
For example, they are currently:

> `website.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/imagehere.jpg`

I would like them to be:

> `website.com/wp-content/uploads/imagehere.jpg`

I have tried going to go to `settings` > `media` and unchecking `Organise my uploads into month- and year-based folders` which didn't work and i've also tried to add a RewriteRule to my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.+?)$ /wp-content/uploads/$3.jpg [L,R=301]
```

After trying both, all my images permalinks are still stay the same, is there something I can do about this?

Answer (score 0):

`Settings` → `Media` → `Organize my uploads into month and year based folders`

This is the right way to do it. Rewrite rules are unnecessary in this case. Keep in mind that this isn't **RETROACTIVE**. Any uploads prior to the change **will keep the same permalink structure to unsure permalinks consistency**.

`Organize my uploads into month and year based folders` is located at the bottom left corner, and should be **un-checked** to remove the month and year from a permalink media file.

You should also flush all rewrite rules, to avoid any troubleshoot. you can use the `flush_rewrite_rules()` at the top of your `function.php` file.

- *Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/*

> Remove rewrite rules and then recreate rewrite rules.

```
/**
* flush_rewrite_rules
* Remove rewrite rules and then recreate rewrite rules.
* @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/
*
* flush_rewrite_rules(); Need to be removed before pushing theme to live.
* Can be replaced by add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'flush_rewrite_rules' ); before pushing theme to live
*/
flush_rewrite_rules();
```

Comment: How can I make uploads prior to this change follow the same URL structure?